Drawing dotted Alphabets in flutter dart using custom painter
I have a following function that calculate the offset points for alphabet A
    void buildAlphabetA() {
    if (alphabetApoints.isEmpty) {
      double startX = 100;
      double startY = 500;
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Offset circlePoint = Offset(startX, startY);
        alphabetApoints.add(circlePoint);
        startX += 10;
        startY -= 30;
        if(i==5){
          double horX=startX;
          double horY=startY;
          for(int j=1;j<4;j++){
            horX+=25;
            alphabetApoints.add(Offset(horX, horY));
          }
        }
      }

      for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
        Offset circlePoint = Offset(startX, startY);
        alphabetApoints.add(circlePoint);
        startX += 10;
        startY += 30;
      }
      alphabetATotalPoints=alphabetApoints.length;
    }      
  }

and following functions draws it using circles
void paintAlphabets(Canvas canvas) {    
    double radius = 7;
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..color = Colors.black;      
      
      for (var element in alphaApoints) {
        canvas.drawCircle(element!, radius, paint);
      }      
  }

After drawing I allow users to draw on canvas. Drawing accuracy is calculated if the drawing point coincides with alphabets point. If I use this approach to draw all the alphabets it will take lot of time. Is there any way to draw these dotted alphabets from jpeg/png etc from assets.
